# CGI - Perl variable inside an href attribute

Tags: perl, cgi

Can I use a variable inside an `href` HTML link so that the user can click on it and it prints it's content or saves it locally?

For example, like in this Perl

```
foreach my $el (@result) {
  print "<TR>";
  print  "<TD align=left><FONT SIZE='4' FACE='Arial,Helvetica'  color=black><a href=   $el->{'name'}></a></FONT></TD>\n";
 }
```

Comment: Yes. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I guess I need to have another script so when user click on the link either it prints the file content in this case excel or save it locally..thanks again for all good people out there much much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Perl sees

```
print "...$el->{'name'}...";
```

which is perfectly fine.

As for whether that generates valid HTML or not, that's a completely separate issue. Did you take care to properly escape the characters that need escaping? What about the quotes around the attribute's value?

Comment: noop does not work even after removing all the quotes around the attribute's value

Comment: Remove? They were *missing*

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your Perl code.

Perhaps `@result` doesn't contain what you think it does?

You could debug it by changing the loop to this temporarily

```
for my $el (@result) {
  printf "<tr><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $el->{name} // 'undef';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, `href=\"". $el->{'name'} . "\"`

```
foreach my $el (@result) {
  print "<TR>";
  print  "<TD align=left><FONT SIZE='4' FACE='Arial,Helvetica'  color=black><a href=\"". $el->{'name'} . "\"></a></FONT></TD>\n";
 }
```